# How to move folder in unix using mv, only when target is on the same drive

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, mv

I need to move a folder using unix mv command, but only if the target is in the same drive or the same filesystem. What would be the best approach?

Comment: drive here you mean "device" ? e.g. same harddisk?

Comment: same device, yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [How to check if two directories or files belong to same filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44250) (https://unix.stackexchange.com/):

> In a shell script on Linux it can be done with [stat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44250):
>
> ```
> stat -c "%d" /path  # returns the decimal device number
> ```

So you can:

```
file1=$(stat -c "%d" /path/file1)
file2=$(stat -c "%d" /path/file2)
```

and then compare.

You can also write like this:

```
if [ $(stat -c "%d" /path/file1) -eq $(stat -c "%d" /path/file1) ]
then
    # mv sentence
fi
```

---

Other option. Also taken from the [Stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44250):

```
if [[ $(df -P /path/file1 | tail -1) = $(df -P /path/file2 | tail -1) ]]
then
    # echo "same filesystem"
    # mv sentence
fi
```

Comment: Do you think it's compatible across linux distributions?

Comment: Just for spreading the better practice, use `$(...)` instead of `\`...\``. The later is deprecated in favor of the former.

Comment: Thanks @Shahbaz , just edited it with your recommendation!

Comment: @zapp I don't know, should test it. My experience with `stat` tells me it is sometimes tricky, at least with SunOS. But being Linux I hope it is compatible. With my Ubuntu 12 it is fine.

Comment: this `%d` outputs different values for different dirs (same partition even) try with your `/` and `/tmp`

Comment: In my case I get the same output, @Kent . Anyway, I added another option - with `df -P /path/file`.

Comment: yep, I thought of `stat` too, so I came with the comment under the question. then I found out the `%d` is not reliable. maybe playing with the `df` or `lsblk` would be the solution. however yours may have problem. e.g. `/` and `/home` are different partitions but same device(disk). the if will return false.  I feel the question is not clear. what if 3 partitions on same device (disk) have 3 different filesystems? say (ext3, ntfs, fat32)?  anyway, +1 your post for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the cleanest solution, but you could use the fact that hard links can't be created between drives.

```
ln /path1/file /path2/file 2> /dev/null
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
    rm /path1/file
fi
```